# How to bind grid to selected tree view item in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

How do I bind grid to selected tree view item in WPF? In short when user of my app clicks on tree view item, then I want to run command that would load some data and present it on grid. Based on item's underlying type I want to bind to different commands.

**XAML**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource GetElementTypeConverter}}" Value="{x:Type Models:SomeType}">
                    // WHAT CODE GOES HERE?
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource GetElementTypeConverter}}" Value="{x:Type Models:SomeOtherType}">
                    // WHAT CODE GOES HERE?
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

I'd like to handle click event in MVVM manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF, we deal with different data types by defining different `DataTemplate`s. In your case, you could already have defined some. If not, do so now, and in these `DataTemplate`s, you can set the relevant `ICommand`s. You can do this in several ways, but one easy way is just to define your content inside a 'blank' `Button`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourDataTypePrefix:YourDataType}">
    <Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <!-- Define your YourDataType item content here -->
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourDataTypePrefix:OtherDataType}">
    <Button Command="{Binding SomeOtherCommand}">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <!-- Define your OtherDataType item content here -->
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

That seems strange that you say you can't select the `TreeViewItem` with that `Button`. However, you could try using a `ToggleButton` to bind to the `TreeViewItem.IsSelected` property instead:

```
<ToggleButton Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}">
    <ToggleButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid>
                <!-- Define your YourDataType item content here -->
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

If that still doesn't work, then use an `AttachedProperty` to handle the `PreviewMouseDown` event on a `Grid` in the `DataTemplate`s. You can find lots of online documentation about handling events with `AttachedProperty`s, so I won't go over that again here. However, if you did that (and that is the better solution), then you could then do something like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourDataTypePrefix:YourDataType}">
    <Grid Attached:MouseEvents.PreviewMouseDown="{Binding SomeCommand}">
        <!-- Define your YourDataType item content here -->
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: This answer seems ok, but I have one problem - now my `TreeViewItem` is not selectable (no blue rectangle around it when I click on it)...

Comment: I think you misunderstood me - by saying that my `TreeViewItem` is not selectable I meant only what I said between the brackets - there's no blue (or any other) selection around the `TreeViewItem`. Apart from that everything works fine - meaning that the command is run.

Comment: Do you want to see the blue selection colour, or not? Try adding a `Margin` to the `Button` if you do want to see it.

Comment: I want to see it :). If I add a `Margin` to it, will it have blue border? But I'd like it to look just like any other selected `TreeViewItem` - and default look is not a blue border - the whole item is blue when selected.

Comment: I thought that the `Button` *might* just be hiding it... it shouldn't really because it doesn't have any `Background` set. I tested this example code and I don't have your problem... it must be something in *your* code that is hiding the `Background`. Try setting the `Background` of the `UIElement`s that you put inside the `Button` to `Transparent`.

Comment: Ok, just so we understand each other - by default my `TreeViewItem` containing the `Button` has no selection and therefore no background colour. When I click the button, background of `TreeViewItem` should become blue. If that's what's going on when you test your code, I'll accept your answer, since there's clearly something wrong with mine.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, then try the `Attached Property` route of handling the `MouseDown` (or similar) event... it's the better option anyway. Take a look at my answer to the [WPF Textbox bind with string data type property should accept only numeric value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011704/wpf-textbox-bind-with-string-data-type-property-should-accept-only-numeric-value/18012041#18012041) question here on Stack Overflow. I show how to create an `Attached Property` for a `TextBox`. You can easily adapt it to work on the `UIElement` class and mouse events instead.